# fix regexp_substr expression

Tags: oracle

Appreciate help to fix the `regexp` -

```
with data as (
  select '1-2' test_col from dual union all
  select '   1   -   2' test_col from dual union all
  select '1 -  ' test_col from dual union all
  select '-2' test_col from dual union all
  select '-' test_col from dual union all
  select '' test_col from dual 
  )select regexp_substr(test_col,'[^- ]+',1) col1,
regexp_substr(test_col,'[^- ]+',2) col2
from data;
```

Expected output -

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | null |
| null | 2 |
| null | null |
| null | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7GJUsSIp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
select regexp_substr(test_col,'^\s*([^-[:space:]]*)\s*-\s*([^-[:space:]]*)\s*$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) col1,
       regexp_substr(test_col,'^\s*([^-[:space:]]*)\s*-\s*([^-[:space:]]*)\s*$', 1, 1, NULL, 2) col2
from   data;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE data (test_col) as
  select '1-2'          from dual union all
  select '   1   -   2' from dual union all
  select '1 -  '        from dual union all
  select '-2'           from dual union all
  select '-'            from dual union all
  select ''             from dual;
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | *null* |
| *null* | 2 |
| *null* | *null* |
| *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kn-wOuzP)

Answer (score 0):

This may be of help as well.

```
with data as 
(
  select '1-2' test_col from dual union all
  select '   1   -   2' test_col from dual union all
  select '1 -  ' test_col from dual union all
  select '-2' test_col from dual union all
  select '-' test_col from dual union all
  select '' test_col from dual 
)
select 
test_col, 
nvl(trim(substr(test_col, 1, regexp_instr(test_col, '( -)(+)|(-)(+)')-1)), 'null') col1,
nvl(regexp_replace(substr(test_col, regexp_instr(test_col, '( -)(+)|(-)(+)') + 1), '-(*)| (*)', null), 'null') col2
from data;
```

Thanks
~ Arnab P